# Highstock Chart not displaying correct dates and no zoom by date

Tags: java, php, mysql, highcharts

I have created a JSFiddle of my chart that I am trying to creating using my data.

I have successfully exported my data from mySQL and the unix timestamp looks to be correct. The first data starts on the 1st January 2004 and the last being yesterday (12th March 2013). However, the chart shows only January 13th - 16th and the times which I don't need. I need it to show the whole data range, IE 2004 - 2013. The zoom by date also doesn't seem to work?

My JSFiddle link is :

http://jsfiddle.net/petenaylor/rJDRB/1/

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

(function($){ // encapsulate jQuery

$(function() {
var seriesOptions = [],
    yAxisOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['Electric', 'Oil', 'Gas'],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

$.each(names, function(i, name) {

    $(function() {

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Energy Prices'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'Electric',

            <?php 
            $result = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM energyprices ORDER BY id ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            extract($row);
            $date = strtotime($row['pDate']); // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
            $data1[] = "[$date, $electric]";
            }
            ?>


            data: [<?php echo join($data1, ',') ?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },{
            name : 'Oil',


            <?php 
            $result = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM energyprices ORDER BY id ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            extract($row);
            $date = strtotime($row['pDate']); // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
            $data2[] = "[$date, $oil]";
            }
            ?>


            data: [<?php echo join($data2, ',') ?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        },{
            name : 'Gas',


            <?php 
            $result = mysql_query (" SELECT * FROM energyprices ORDER BY id ASC") or die (mysql_error());
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            extract($row);
            $date = strtotime($row['pDate']); // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
            $data3[] = "[$date, $gas]";
            }
            ?>


            data: [<?php echo join($data3, ',') ?>],
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});

 });

});



// create the chart when all data is loaded
function createChart() {

    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

});
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your data x should be multiply by 1000, because you need JS timestamps, and also sorted by x, ascending.

Comment: Thanks for you help, do I adjust this in the jquery?

Comment: Well, only what you need is getting value and multiply by 1000, so what you mean adjust in jquery?

Comment: Sorry, can you let me know which data needs to be multiplied by 1000? Do you mean the data that is the value? As in my example, Oil, Gas, Electricity values?

Comment: In this [1073174400, 0] first value.